# Merging dataframes is causing to loose rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe on which I divide into 3 sub dataframes. Then I am applying aggregate functions. After than, I merge the 3 dataframes.

However, when comparing the number of rows prior and post the merge, it shows a significant loss, although I used a command to fill in blanks to preserve the row count. I think the aggregation code is that trimmed everything. Maybe there is a better way to write that portion of the code which will fix the rest of it.

```
In: df.info()
Out:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 505960 entries, 640051 to 204623
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id             505960 non-null int64
session_number 505960 non-null int64
date           505960 non-null datetime64[ns]
purchases      505960 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(3)
memory usage: 19.3 MB

In: df.shape
Out: (505960, 4)

In: 
#slice main dataframe
df_test=df[['id','purchases','session_number','date']].copy()

#aggregations I THINK HERE IS THE PROBLEM SOURCE!
df_1=df_test.groupby(['id'])["purchases"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()).reset_index()
df_2=df_test.groupby(['id'])["session_number"].apply(lambda y : y.max()-y.min()).astype(int).reset_index()
df_3=df_test.groupby(['id'])["date"].apply(lambda z : z.max()-z.min()).reset_index()

#merge dfs sequentially by id
df_a=pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df=pd.merge(df_a, df_3, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)

in: df.shape
Out: (292291, 4)
```

You can see that my rows shrunk from 505,960 to 292,291! What am I doing wrong with the aggregation portion of the code and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the given code and metadata information about the data, `groupby` would aggregate records with the same id into a single `GroupBy` object, hence the total number of record counts will decrease if the id's are not unique. The count of **unique** id's should be same as the final count of records after `groupby`.

`df['id'].nunique()` will give you the count of unique id's, which should match your final count.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `df_test.groupby(['id'])` this, it generates a GroupBy object and it sets group key as index an, which is 'id' in this case.

Hence, do the following rather:

```
df_a = df_1.merge(df_2, left_index = True, right_index =True).fillna(0)
df = df_a.merge(df_3, left_index = True, right_index =True).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I think the problem is the way I am aggregating by doing it sequentially and therefore trimming at each step which eventually shrinks and produces a inner join therefore. Could this be the issue?